# Rest API - Multi-Column Sort issue

Tags: rest

I have seen few articles about Best Practices with REST API and they are suggesting belo for multi column sort.
GET /users?sort_by=**-last_modified,+email**

```
https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pagination/
```

When I am using this approach, I see that - works fine but + gets replaced by a space.

A quick google indicates that + is a special character after ? in URL. What am I missing out here?

```
> The following characters have special meaning in the path component of
> your URL (the path component is everything before the '?'):   ";" |
> "/" | "?"
> 
> In addition to those, the following characters have special meaning in
> the query part of your URL (everything after '?'). Therefore, if they
> are after the '?' you need to escape them:   ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" |
> "+" | "$" | ","
> 
> For a more in-depth explanation, see the RFC.
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing out here?

History, mostly.

[U+002B](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002B) (+) is a sub-delim, in the context of a URI, and can be used freely in the query part; see [RFC 3986 Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

But *on the web*, a common source of query data is HTML form submissions; when we submit a form, the processing engine collects the key value pairs from the form and creates an [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application/x-www-form-urlencoded) character sequence, which becomes the query of the URI.

Because this is such a common case, the query parsers in web server frameworks often default to reversing the encoding before giving your bespoke code access to the data.

Which means that in your web logs, you would see:

```
/users?sort_by=-last_modified,+email
```

because that's the URI that you received, but in your parameter mapping you would see

```
"sort_by" = "-last_modified, email"
```

Because the "form data" is being decoded before you get to look at it.

Form urlencoding has an explicit step in it that replaces any spaces (U+0020) with U+002B, and U+002B is instead percent-encoded.

To check if this is what is going on, try instead the following request:

```
GET /users?sort_by=-last_modified,%2Bemail
```

What I expect you will find is that the plus you are looking for now appears in your form parameters:

```
"sort_by" = "-last_modified,+email"
```